# Glyph origins of the character 微

Tags: glyph-origin, character-components

How does this character meaning become "small/tiny"?
So many sources tell me that it's semantic 彳 + "phonetic" , but what exactly is ? I've never seen this character elsewhere before. Could this possibly like 德 and 得, where the original character was missing the 彳 part? However, I haven't found any answer that explains the  component, so was wondering if anyone can enlighten me, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [《說文・彳部》](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77389&page=71)
>
> > <kbd>[image]</kbd>
> >
> > 隱行也。从「彳」，「」聲。
> >
> > 「微」 ([Baxter-Sagart OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Baxter%E2%80%93Sagart_(2014)): **/*məj/**), to travel [somewhere] under stealth. From semantic 「彳」 (*to walk*) and phonetic 「」 (**/*məj/**).

Strictly speaking, 「微」 is just a complexified character from 「」. Characters naturally become more complex over time for disambiguation purposes, as simpler characters tend to be used and reused for other senses or as [rebus characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebus#Rebus_principle)/[phonetic loans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_classification#Borrowed_characters_.28.E5.81.87.E5.80.9F.29), causing them to be overloaded with definitions and more easily subjected to shape distortions, and thus increasingly difficult to comprehend.

Since 「」 is the original character for the meaning *small, slight*, then in terms of glyph origins, 「微」 is built from semantic 「彳」 and **doubly semantic and phonetic 「」** . 「彳」 is simply a semantic indicator appended on to 「微」 to extend the meaning *small, slight* to *travelling under stealth*.

So, all this begs the question - what exactly is 「」 supposed to be？

---

#### Glyph origins of 「」

<kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
[甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
[image]
[京都](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)2146
[合集27996](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=27996&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
[金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
[image]
[史墻盤](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shi_Qiang_pan)
[集成10175](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=10175&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[戰國](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period)・[楚](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_(state))
[簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
[image]
56.35
[九店楚簡](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B9%9D%E5%BA%97%E6%A5%9A%E7%B0%A1)</kbd>
<kbd>[篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script)
[image]
[人部](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77391&page=6)
[說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi)</kbd>
<kbd>[楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
[image]</kbd>

「」 is constructed from semantic [「髟」 (*picture of a person with long hair*)](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=7138) and semantic [「攵・攴」 (*picture of a hand holding a hitting implement*](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=31257) > *to strike, to hit*), inferring the meaning *delicate, slight* through the action of *cutting off a full growth of hair into a more elegant and delicate state*.

*Shuōwén*'s

> [《說文・人部》](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77391&page=6)
>
> > <kbd>[image]</kbd>
> >
> > 妙也。从「人」，从「攴」。「豈」省聲。
> >
> > (**/*məj/**) [means] *delicate*. From semantic 「人」 (*person*), semantic 「攴」 (*to strike*), and reduced phonetic 「豈」 (**/*C.qʰˤəjʔ/**).

is probably a misunderstanding. [「豈」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=1911) may have originated from an alteration of [「壴」 (*picture of a drum*)](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=6218) into 「豈」 (*beating of victory drums* > *triumphant music*, now written as 「凱」), and *Shuōwén* has confused the top part of 「豈」 with the top-[left] part of 「髟」.

> <kbd>商
> 甲
> [image: 壴]
> [甲](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)2770
> [合集27694](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=27694&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>西周
> 金
> [image: 壴]
> 壴鼎
> [集成1175](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=1175&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[春秋](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_and_Autumn_period)
> 金
> [image: 壴]
> 王孫遺者鐘
> [集成261](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=261&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>戰國・楚
> 簡
> [image: 壴]
> 性自命出49
> [郭店楚簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guodian_Chu_Slips)</kbd><kbd>戰國・楚
> 簡
> [image: 敳]
> 1.011
> 信陽竹書簡</kbd>
> <kbd>篆
> [image: 豈]
> [豈部](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77390&page=33)
> 說文解字</kbd><kbd>[西漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Western_Han)
> [隸](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script)
> [image: 豈]
> 縱橫145
> [馬王堆帛書](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mawangdui_Silk_Texts)</kbd><kbd>[三國](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Kingdoms)・[魏](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cao_Wei)
> 隸
> [image: 豈]
> 魏封孔羨碑</kbd>
> 　
> <kbd>楷
> [image: 豈]</kbd>
>
> For reference, shape derivation of 「豈」. Shapes 1-4 refer to 「壴」. Shape 5 is 「敳」, with the left-hand component as 「壴」 but the top-left part written as a rotated 「山」. This sets the scene for the confusion of 「豈」 and 「」 in *Shuōwén*. Forms 6-9 refer to 「豈」, which all inherit the (rotated) 「山」 shape.

---

**References:**

- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- 李學勤《字源》
- [漢語多功能字庫](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/)
- [小學堂字形演變](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian)
- [國學大師](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/)

  - [郭沫若《甲骨文合集》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/)
  - [中國社會科學院考古研究所《殷周金文集成》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/)

Answer (score 0):

> [W]hat exactly is ? [...] Could this possibly like 德 and 得, where the original character was missing the 彳 part?

Yes, exactly. From [Unihan for U+22F38](https://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/GetUnihanData.pl?codepoint=%F0%A2%BC%B8):

[image: Unihan entry for U+22F38 with picture of character]

This character's etymology, from [ctext](https://ctext.org/dictionary.pl?if=en&char=%F0%A2%BC%B8) quoting 《說文》:

> 妙也。从人从攴，豈省聲。
> Mysterious/clever. From Man (人), from Rap (攴), [with] phonetic 豈 reduced.

Comment: In paleography and Chinese linguistics, 《說文》 is usually only a last resort if you can't find anything better.

Comment: @dROOOze I see. Would it have been more appropriate for me to give a comment instead of an answer then?

Comment: sorry, but I feel shuowen forces too many words to be phonetic-semantic, even when it makes no sense to me. In this case 豈 sounds nothing like  or 微, It doesn't really explain the character components, and how 攴 brings any semantic meaning

Comment: @Fishuman I believe 豈, , and 微 rhymed in Middle Chinese. This is preserved in Cantonese (hei2, mei4, and mei4 respectively).